# Popup Menu as new user control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am trying to implement a sort of popup menu or window in my WPF app.  I am using the MVVM light framework to message and switch between views.  What I want is to open a new UserControl that includes some settings that a user can adjust.

```
<Window x:Class="RTWPFApp.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Re App"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="459"
        Width="795">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding AudioSettingsViewModel}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

How can I open AudioSettingsViewModel as a separate popup on top of CurrentView?

Answer (score 0):

You can put `<ContentControl Content="{Binding AudioSettingsViewModel}" />` inside a popup control

```
 <Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsAudioSettingsOpen}">
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding AudioSettingsViewModel}" />
    </Popup>
 </Grid>
```

`IsAudioSettingsOpen` will be your property on your Window's ViewModel though which you can control the opening and closing of your popup.